# [AssemblyScript]Is there any way to bundle multiple Typescript files into a single Typescript file?

Tags: typescript, bundle, bundler

I'm using AssemblyScript to use WebAssembly for improving performance of my image processing algorithm. AssemblyScript is basically Typescript code, but it is not supporting `import` or `export` in current version.
I thought if I could bundle all of my AssemblyScript files into a single AssemblyScript file (It must be same as Typescript), I might be able to code AssemblyScript as I write Typescript files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using some old prototype version `0.3.0` from `npm` repositary (which not maintained anymore). You should install latest version via [`npm install --save-dev AssemblyScript/assemblyscript`](https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript#getting-started)

Comment: You are correct! I successfully used `import` syntax as I thought.